# Getting error with the newly configured webpack 2

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2

I am trying to configure webpack 2 for my react development app. Seems like there is something I am missing below is my webpack.config.dev

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
        import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
        import path from 'path';
        var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

        var loaders = [
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: true
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'postcss-loader'
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
        ];

        export default {
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
            },
            devtool: 'eval-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
            entry: {
                app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
                vendor: ["react", "react-dom"]
            },
            target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
            output: {
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Note: Physical src are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
                publicPath: '/',
                filename: "[name].entry.chunk.js"
            },
            plugins: [
                new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: '[name].[hash].js', }),
                new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
                new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'), // Tells React to build in either dev or prod modes. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html (See bottom)
                    __DEV__: true
                }),
                new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
                new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
                new HtmlWebpackPlugin({     // Create HTML file that includes references to bundled CSS and JS.
                    template: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
                    filename: 'index.html',
                    inject: 'body',
                    minify: {
                        removeComments: true,
                        collapseWhitespace: true
                    },
                })
            ],
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel']},
                    {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
                    {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"},
                    {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
                    {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
                    {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
                    {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
                    {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
                        loader: loaders,
                      }) },
                    {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json"}
                ]
            },
        };
```

This is my github repo https://github.com/sourabh-garg/Webpack-2-starter-kit please clone it and and run npm install followed by npm start.

When I run it I get

```
    ERROR in ./src/index.js
    Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:0)

     render(
     "<h1>Hello World!</h1>", document.getElementById('app')
        );
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: index.js in this repository is empty, but make sure you've imported React to compile jsx

Comment: Hi Noam sorry for that. I have updated repo now. Same issue

Comment: the repository is too big, try to git ignore `node_modules` and `.idea`

Comment: BTW the index.js file won't render because it's not in the correct format, you should create a class with render function, or just return a function with the content of the render function (see last example here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down)

Comment: Done. Can you try running the repo. Mean while I will try the way you suggested. :)